# Inner UL overlaps Border Radius

Tags: jquery, css, html

I have a div with a border radius of 20px. The inner UL overlaps the border radius. I would like this ul to be scrollable, so I cant just apply a border radius to the list aswell..

Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: can you give more information about the elements in question? some css or markup maybe?

Comment: @Aljullu Sorry, I am trying to use this with iScroll in a jquery mobile application which means my wrapper has `position: absolute;` which breaks Aljullu's code. My outputted code is: `<div class="products" id="results_wrapper" style="overflow-x: hidden; overflow-y: hidden; "><div id="scroller" style="-webkit-transform-origin-x: 0px; -webkit-transform-origin-y: 0px; position: absolute; -webkit-transition-duration: 0ms; left: 0px; top: 0px; "><ul>
              <li>1</li>
              <li>10</li></ul></div></div>`

Comment: My CSS is: `#results .products{
 height: 300px;
 width: 100%;
 border: 3px solid red;
 border-radius: 20px;
 background: white;
 position: relative;
 overflow: hidden;
}
#results .products div#scroller{
 background: black;
 height: 100%;
 width: 100%;
 position:absolute;
}
#results .products ul{
 list-style-type:none;
 padding:0;
}
#results .products ul li {background: rgb(255,255,255); /* Old browsers */
height: 75px;

border-bottom: 1px solid #999;
width: 100%;
}`

Answer (score 4):

Try putting *overflow: hidden* in the wrapping div to prevent the inner UL to overlap the border radius.

Then, set *overflow: scroll* in the inner UL to make it scrollable if there isn't enough vertical space.

I made a simple example:

```
<style>
#wrapper {
    background: #DDD;
    border-radius: 20px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
ul {
    background: #AAA;
    margin: 0;
    max-height: 100px;
    overflow: auto;
    padding: 0;
}
</style>
<div id="wrapper">
    <ul>
        <li>Item 1</li>
        <li>Item 2</li>
        <li>Item 3</li>
        <li>Item 4</li>
        <li>Item 5</li>
        <li>Item 6</li>
        <li>Item 7</li>
        <li>Item 8</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to fix this is to make the padding of the div bigger